# GWT: how to check the selection event for a CellTable with a SelectionModel

Tags: java, gwt

We use a sortable CellTable with two columns, with a SingleSelectionModel.
Now one of the columns is filled with ButtonCells.

And the problem is: if I click the first time directly on the button of a row, only the row gets selected and it doesn't directly fires the Event for the Button. I have to click a second time.

How can I change this? How can I directly fire the event of the Button?

Comment: Show a example of your code

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using? I thought that bug was fixed at one point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a FieldUpdater on your Button Column:

```
column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Auction, String>() {
  @Override
  public void update(int index, Auction object, String value) {
    // The user clicked on the button for the passed auction.
  }
});
```

The [CellSampler](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler) from GWT's docs has a direct example of clickable buttons. Cheers.

Another option is is overriding the Button's [onBrowserEvent()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ButtonCell.html#onBrowserEvent(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context,%20com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element,%20java.lang.String,%20com.google.gwt.dom.client.NativeEvent,%20com.google.gwt.cell.client.ValueUpdater)) method.

Comment: Hello Lev, the Button is clickable, thats not the point. The Point is, that it is only clickable after selecting the row. I use the FieldUpdater now, but this is only working  after the selection

Comment: posting potential solution in the original answer, hope it helps. I do remember running into something similar with a SingleSelectionModel attached to the table.

Comment: oh thank you. I will check this option